# Tracking outbound links using ajax (javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a question regarding this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078233/560972

As i understand, the most common problem using JS (Ajax) to track outgoing link clicks is that sometimes user leaves page before (faster) the script can grab the data...?

So maybe it is possible to force some sort of delay in order to let script finish recording and then let user navigate away to other site? Delay when link is clicked and navigation away occurs

Will this help? I suppose ~200ms/300ms won't be visible for user but it could be enough for ajax call?

What you do think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With jquery:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   //check that it is offsite
   if($(this).attr("href").indexOf("http")==1) {
      //prevent the redirect;
      e.preventDefault();
      //do your tracking 
      $.ajax{
          url: 'yourtracking.php',
          data: "link=" + $(this).attr("href"),
          complete: function(){
              //now do the redirect
              window.location = $(this).attr("href");
          }

     }
  }
});
```

Comment: the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2078233/560972 all use jquery for a reason. This isn't trivial to do without jquery.

Comment: For my situation - there is difference. Thanks

Comment: Also this is just standard link tracking, but what about forced delay and the problem of missing some clicks?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); prevents the link click from doing anything. the complete option of $.ajax is a callback and will only execute once the ajax request has completed.