# Tracking clicks with jquery - php tracking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hyperlink

I'm trying to track the number of clicks on a specific link. But first I need to test my script for all links, regardless of id.

I have this between the head tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

somewhere between the body tags, I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('a').click(function(e) {

   // ++++ Not sure what this condition does ++++
   if($(this).attr("href").indexOf("http")==1) {

      //prevent the redirect;
      e.preventDefault();

      //do your tracking 
      $.ajax({
          url: 'tracking.php',
          data: "link=" + $(this).attr("href"),
          complete: function(){
              //now do the redirect
              window.location = $(this).attr("href");
          } 

     }); 
  } 

   }); 


   }); 
   </script>
```

Just to test, tracking.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$tckfile = fopen("tracking.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Test" .  "\r\n";
fwrite($tckfile, $txt);
fclose($tckfile);
?>
```

I made the changes and reloaded my page, but doesn't seems to work. I found this code on stackoverflow and not sure would it works.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you mention where you found it? The condition checks that the link contains the text `"http"` in it's `href` attribute. Also if there are any errors please show us.

Comment: Try `alert($(this).attr("href").indexOf("http"));` beofre that `if(){}` block which you don't understand.

Comment: Please note that your code will fail if your anchor tags look like this `<a href="/contact.php">Contact Us!</a>`

Comment: I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337982/tracking-outbound-links-using-ajax-javascript . I don't see errors, but my php does not seem to execute. Ok , I will try the alert. My link is a full link with http, so it should work then.

Comment: @monkeyzeus That's interesting, the alert displays 0 (zero) with a link tag that looks like this: <a style="margin: 1em 0 0 0;" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="http://www.example.com/subfolder/"> My link 01</span></a> - Not sure I understand why because it contains http, and the alert displays -1 with a link tag that looks like this: <a href="/subfolder/hello/">My link 02</a>, That one is because it doesn't have http, right? Thanks guys

Comment: You could just add a `track-me` class to each anchor you want to track and listen for the user to click it like this `$('a.track-me').click(function(e) {/*Tracking code*/};`. The assumption made by Matthew Graves in that other StackOverflow question is faulty and coded wrong.

Comment: @monkeyzeus That's an excellent idea. Thanks so much for your help a+

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `indexOf("http")`, or the links without `http` can't be counted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('a').click(function(e) {
   if($(this).attr("href")){
      //prevent the redirect;
      e.preventDefault();

      //do your tracking 
      $.ajax({
          url: 'tracking.php',
          data: "link=" + $(this).attr("href"),
          complete: function(){
              //now do the redirect
              window.location = $(this).attr("href");
          } 

     }); 
  } 

   }); 


   }); 
   </script>
```